# Django- using same html template for the same purpose but for different users- blog web

Tags: django, templates, web, web-applications

I'm working on a blog web app and I want to know if there is a way to make 1 html template called blog.html for example that its content is different for each user who made it?
Like if I have 200 users who create a blog in my web app and I dont want to make for each of them a special template..
I mean I want every one to have his unique blog but using the same blog.html template and then I can direct to their own unique blog using different end to the path.. and i'll take that end from the model field of the user..

like I can iterate through user.name model field and set it as the end path.. like in the ListView.. and I want each end path will direct to the specific blog using the same html template but dynamicly.

Anyway thanks for helping and if there is some one who build web apps with Django and want to work together with me, ill glad to :)

Hope you understand my intention.

Comment: Does each user have 1 blog or do you want to have a list of blogs for each user?

Comment: 1 blog page per user, but in the future ill add an archive for each user I guess that will store posts the user decided to move there

Comment: And the blog content will be editable for the user but other user who will watch other user's blog, will see the same blog page but won't have the option to edit.